# Init dash.js with certain quality

Tags: javascript, dash.js

**Question**
How can I initialize dash.js with the correct quality before the stream is initialized?

**Problem:** 
While setting a quality with dash.js, I get green artifacts when playback starts (see image below). Quality is set after stream initialization by responding to the `STREAM_INITIALIZED` event. [image: Green artifacts]

**Context:** I am trying to create an application with a dash where the user should be able to select a playback quality. This selection is will be set by using a cookie like this: `cookies.set('preferredQuality', quality.value);`, where value corresponds to either 0, 1, 2 or 3 (set in dash.js with [setQualityFor](http://cdn.dashjs.org/latest/jsdoc/module-MediaPlayer.html#setQualityFor) and [setAutoSwitchQualityFor](http://cdn.dashjs.org/latest/jsdoc/module-MediaPlayer.html#setAutoSwitchQualityFor) set to `false`).

Then in the logic for creating the dash instance, I listen for the `STREAM_INITIALIZED` event and try to set the quality there

`this.dashJsInstance.on(dashjs.MediaPlayer.events.STREAM_INITIALIZED, this.onStreamInitialized, this);`

```js
onStreamInitialized: function() {
  const quality = cookies.get('preferredQuality');
  if (quality !== -1) {
    this.dashJsInstance.setAutoSwitchQualityFor('video', false);
    this.dashJsInstance.setQualityFor('video', quality);
  }
},
```

This results in the green artifacts shown in the image.

Comment: Did you happen to find a solution for this issue? I'm still facing this problem on dashjs v2.9.2

Comment: @iamprem added some code, hope this works out for you!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the correct answer, but solved it by listening to the `onFragmentLoaded` event. This is by no means the best answer, but it works. We implemented it by doing something like this:

```
onFragmentLoaded: function(e) {
    if (e.request && e.request.type === 'InitializationSegment') {
        const preferredQuality = quality // Preferred quality;
        const currentQuality = current // Current quality;

        if (currentQuality !== preferredQuality) {
            this.dashJsInstance.setQualityFor('video', preferredQuality);
            this.dashJsInstance.setAutoSwitchQualityFor('video', false);
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: Issue that I opened with dashjs which is probably the root cause for this issue: https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js/issues/2968